# Is it possible to show an Overlay/Marker in an instantiated StreetViewPanorama?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm in the process of setting up a bit of a panorama tour for a client and I've noticed a problem which I can't seem to resolve.

Markers aren't appearing in my StreetViewPanorama.

Using some code derived from official examples I've been able to replicate the problem:

- Works: http://jsfiddle.net/kStR3/1/
- Does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/6KhkH/1/

The difference seems to be in how the StreetViewPanorama is obtained...

In the example that works `panorama` is sourced directly from the map object: `panorama = map.getStreetView()`

In the example that fails `panorama` is created via `panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama` and is assigned to the map with `map.setStreetView(panorama)`.

It is unfortunate, but in my case I am unable to use `map.getStreetView()` due to the fact that there are a variable number of panoramas running in a slideshow fashion.

Is there a way I can get Markers/Overlays to show in an instantiated StreetViewPanorama?

I guess a fallback would be to overlay some `<div>` elements and calculate their screen position and visibility based on `.getPov()` and `.getPosition()`, but that's probably more work than I have budget for.

Comment: There is a partial solution, and I'm kicking myself for not reading this properly in the API reference to begin with:

"Overlays which you display on a map may be displayed on a Street View panorama by treating the panorama as a substitute for the Map object, calling setMap() and passing the StreetViewPanorama as an argument instead of a map"

So in this case I could create two sets of Markers. One set for my map, and one set for my panoramas.

This will solve my immediate needs, however I'd still be interested to know if there was a proper solution which did not require duplicating anything.

Comment: Can you post another fiddle with it working? I'm running setMap and passing the StreetViewPanorama, but the marker isn't showing up. marker.getMap() points to the panorama, marker.getVisible() is true. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Documentation means something like that:

```
 var infoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: 42.34550, lng: -71.09830 },
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=info|FFFF00',
        title: 'Info'
    });
    cafeMarker.setMap(panorama);
```